# Why app instance is null with import command?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I try to add https://github.com/HJ29/vue3-tabs in **vuejs3** and as I do not need tabs on any page I want
to reference it only on 1 page and importing app from *src/main.js* I got error that app instance in null.
I in *src/views/test.vue* :

```
<template>
  <div>
    
    stringVar:{{ stringVar}}
    <h3>Basic Example</h3>
    <tabs
      v-model="selectedTab"
    >
      <tab
        class="tab"
        v-for="(tab, i) in tabs"
        :key="`t${i}`"
        :val="tab"
        :label="tab"
        :indicator="true"
      />
    </tabs>
    <tab-panels
      v-model="selectedTab"
      :animate="true"
    >
      <tab-panel
        v-for="(tab, i) in tabs"
        :key="`tp${i}`"
        :val="tab"
      >
        {{ tab }}
      </tab-panel>
    </tab-panels>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { ref, onMounted, reactive } from 'vue'

  import { Tabs, Tab, TabPanels, TabPanel } from 'vue3-tabs'
  import app from '@/main.js'

  console.log('src/views/test.vue app::')
  console.log(app) // In console I see that this var is empty

  app.use(Tabs)

  export default {
    name: 'testTrePage',
    components: {
      Tabs,
      Tab,
      TabPanels,
      TabPanel
    },
    setup() {
      let stringVar = ref('Init value')
      const tabs = ['A', 'B', 'C']
      const state = reactive({
        selectedTab: tabs[1]
      })

      const testInit = async () => {
      }

      onMounted(testInit)

      return {
        stringVar,
        tabs,
      }
    } // setup() {

  }
</script>
```

So I got console error:

```
test.vue?2762:42 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined
```

In *src/main.js* I have :

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'
import store from './store' // src/store/index.js

import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router/router.js'

import DKToast from 'vue-dk-toast'
import mitt from 'mitt'

import 'bootstrap'
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'

axios.defaults.crossDomain = true

const app = createApp(App)
const emitter = mitt()
app.config.globalProperties.$emitter = emitter

app.use(store)
app.config.globalProperties.$store = store

app.use(router)
app.config.globalProperties.$router = router

app.use(DKToast, {
  duration: 5000,
  positionY: 'top', // 'top' or 'bottom'
  positionX: 'right' // 'right' or 'left'
})
export default app.config.globalProperties
app.config.globalProperties.toast = DKToast

const rootInstance = app.mount('#app')
```

I use construction :

```
import app from '@/main.js'
```

and it works ok when I need to use some external components...

But why it does not work in src/views/test.vue with tabs?

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "yt3",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.20.0-0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "mitt": "^2.1.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.4",
    "vee-validate": "^4.0.0-beta.18",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-dk-toast": "^1.1.4",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-rc.1",
    "vue-select": "^3.10.8",
    "vue3-tabs": "^0.1.4",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-rc.1",
    "yup": "^0.29.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^5.1.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0"
  }
}
```

**MODIFIED BLOCK :**
I moved into src/main.js lines :

```
import { Tabs, Tab, TabPanels, TabPanel } from 'vue3-tabs'

...

app.use(Tabs)
app.use(Tab)
app.use(TabPanels)
app.use(TabPanel)

export default app.config.globalProperties
app.config.globalProperties.toast = DKToast

app.mount('#app')
```

and in *src/views/test.vue* :

```
<template>
  <div>
    
    selectedTab:{{ selectedTab}}<br>
    stringVar:{{ stringVar}}<br>
    tabs:{{ tabs}}
    <h3>Basic Example</h3>
    <tabs
      v-model="selectedTab"
    >
      <tab
        class="tab"
        v-for="(tab, i) in tabs"
        :key="`t${i}`"
        :val="tab"
        :label="tab"
        :indicator="true"
      />
    </tabs>
    <tab-panels
      v-model="selectedTab"
      :animate="true"
    >
      <tab-panel
        v-for="(tab, i) in tabs"
        :key="`tp${i}`"
        :val="tab"
      >
        {{ tab }}
      </tab-panel>
    </tab-panels>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { ref, onMounted, reactive } from 'vue'

  import { Tabs, Tab, TabPanels, TabPanel } from 'vue3-tabs'
  export default {
    name: 'testTrePage',
    components: {
      Tabs,
      Tab,
      TabPanels,
      TabPanel
    },
    setup () {
      let stringVar = ref('Init value')
      const tabs = ['A', 'B', 'C']
      const selectedTab = ref(2)
      const state = reactive({
        selectedTab: tabs[1]
      })

      const testOnMounted = async () => {
        console.log('testOnMounted!!!::')
      }

      onMounted(testOnMounted)

      return {
        stringVar,
        tabs,
        selectedTab
        // ...toRefs(state)
      }
    } // setup() {

  }
</script>
```

and I got error :

```
[Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function. 
  at <Anonymous modelValue=2 onUpdate:modelValue=fn > 
  at <TestTrePage onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< null > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>
```

and what I see in browser : *https://prnt.sc/vmmgxn*

What is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to export `app` inside `main.js`

Comment: Do you mean like : export default app.config.globalProperties
app.config.globalProperties.toast = DKToast
app.mount('#app')
export { app }
?   That does not work...

Comment: Could you please to give format of export in main.js ?